# Data between test and production environments are different

Tags: sql, teradata

The count(*) of a table in both Test and Production return the same value. However, a user of the table was doing some validation/testing and noticed that the sum of a column/field is different between the 2 environments. Being the better SQL user between the 2 of us, I'm trying to figure out how to find the discrepancies.

What's a good way to do so? This isn't that big of a table (~1 mill) but I'd like to keep the query/statement rather small

This is in Teradata

Comment: What database are we dealing with?

Comment: Between Production and Test, do the primary keys of the table match? Also, could we see column names and types so we know what we are dealing with? You don't have to give us the entire table structure, just a snip of it.

Comment: sql server? oracle? mysql? other?

Comment: My bad, this is in Teradata, which uses its own flavor of SQL but basically the same as TSQL

Comment: @guildsbounty yes, the primary keys match. I don't want to give out any part of the the table definition, but there are a lot of character fields. A few decimal fields here and there

Comment: Should they actually match?

Comment: Create a temp table in test and populate it with the production data.  Then, in test, run a select query where the primary keys match but something else doesn't.

Comment: Are the test and production environments on the same physical Teradata system?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here is a framework for you to build off of then. Since you are looking at sums and the like, you'll need to assemble most of the WHERE clause for this, since I don't have enough information to know what you are summing. So, I'll write this to find discrepencies in the rows themselves...

```
SELECT t1.id
FROM Production.[schema].table1 t1
INNER JOIN Test.[schema].table1 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.column <> t2.column
....
```

Just push the columns you want to compare into the WHERE clause...this will sync up the two tables from TEST and PROD and let you look for differences between columns. It will return a list of row ids where there is a mismatch.

Comment: Okay, this looks pretty painless and easy. Thanks

Comment: If it works, it will also be pretty painless and easy to Accept the answer ... just a reminder.